# Adding a whole row to a DataSet within a for

Tags: c#

I'm going to show you my code, and explain underneath.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dsSaved = manageSavedjob.GetJobByID(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SavedJobID"].ToString()));

                    dt.Columns.Add("JobID");
                    dt.Columns.Add("JobConID");
                    dt.Columns.Add("jobTitle");
                    dt.Columns.Add("jobInfo");
                    dt.Columns.Add("priceFrom");
                    dt.Columns.Add("priceTo");
                    dt.Columns.Add("dateSent");
                    dt.Columns.Add("lastUpdated");
                    dt.Columns.Add("postUser");
                    dt.Columns.Add("address");
                    dt.Columns.Add("workers");


                    workRow[0] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JobID"].ToString());
                    workRow[1] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JobConID"].ToString());  
                    workRow[2] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["jobTitle"].ToString();
                    workRow[3] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["jobInfo"].ToString();
                    workRow[4] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["priceFrom"].ToString());
                    workRow[5] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["priceTo"].ToString());
                    workRow[6] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dateSent"].ToString();
                    workRow[7] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lastUpdated"].ToString();
                    workRow[8] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["postUser"].ToString();
                    workRow[9] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["address"].ToString();
                    workRow[10] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["workers"].ToString());



                    dt.Rows.Add(workRow);
                    dsDisplay.Tables.Add(dt);

                    count = dsDisplay.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    workRow = dt.NewRow();
                }
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to recieve a whole row filled with details from the database(see dsSaved), and upon getting that, adding it to a workRow{ DataRow workRow = dt.NewRow(); }. I'm then putting it in the datatable, and adding the datatable to @dsDisplay. Then restarting the workRow and @dt.

Problem is that. @dsDisplay seems to be deleted and done from scrap everytime @i gets bigger by one. I'm trying to add rows to @dsDisplay, not recreate it with the new row. Help, please.

Comment: So why you using dsDisplay.Tables.Add(dt); to add new datatable in every iteration? You need to create dt and add it to dsDisplay before loop. And in loop you need to add new row to dt. [Loot at example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's exactly your specification and your description a bit of confusing, but you can try this,

```
DataSet dsSaved = null;
        DataSet ds = null;
        DataTable dt = null;
        DataSet dsDisplay = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dsSaved = manageSavedjob.GetJobByID(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SavedJobID"].ToString()));

            dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("JobID");
            dt.Columns.Add("JobConID");
            dt.Columns.Add("jobTitle");
            dt.Columns.Add("jobInfo");
            dt.Columns.Add("priceFrom");
            dt.Columns.Add("priceTo");
            dt.Columns.Add("dateSent");
            dt.Columns.Add("lastUpdated");
            dt.Columns.Add("postUser");
            dt.Columns.Add("address");
            dt.Columns.Add("workers");


            DataRow workRow = dt.NewRow();

            workRow[0] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JobID"].ToString());
            workRow[1] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JobConID"].ToString());
            workRow[2] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["jobTitle"].ToString();
            workRow[3] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["jobInfo"].ToString();
            workRow[4] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["priceFrom"].ToString());
            workRow[5] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["priceTo"].ToString());
            workRow[6] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dateSent"].ToString();
            workRow[7] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lastUpdated"].ToString();
            workRow[8] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["postUser"].ToString();
            workRow[9] = dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["address"].ToString();
            workRow[10] = Convert.ToInt32(dsSaved.Tables[0].Rows[0]["workers"].ToString());



            dt.Rows.Add(workRow);
            dsDisplay.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
```